# What is the best way for two programs on the same machine to communicate with each other

Tags: c#, c++, ipc, communication

I need to pass some data (integers) from one (C++) program to another (C#). What is the fastest way to do this?

P.S.: OS: Windows XP

Comment: The answer might be different on Windows as opposed to something based on Unix, and C# runs well on OSs other than Windows.  Why don't you specify your OS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My personal preference for this, given that you're using C++ and C# both, and it's on the same system, would be to use Pipes.

They work very well from [native code (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx) as well as from C# via [NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx) and [NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx).

However, there are other options for [Interprocess Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx), any of which would work.

Comment: I think you mean named pipes, not pipes.  Pipes and named pipes are different IPC mechanisms.

Comment: Pipes include both Named Pipes and Anonymous pipes.  You could, technically, use anonymous pipes if one process is launching the other, but otherwise, you'd want named pipes.  Both are, technically, "Pipes", though. From MS: "There are two types of Pipes...", see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365137(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Shared memory would be the fastest but named pipes are pretty fast too and much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a run-down of the available options. Your best bet is probably a [pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365780%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Please replace the "tinyurl" address with the actual address.

Comment: I'll just leave it alone instead of fighting with you... lol sorry

Comment: @cic: so done. Sorry - it contained brackets, messing up the formatting, and I haven't memorised the escape codes yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using files would be the simplest way.  If you need the speed, then network sockets may be a good option.

Comment: A mailslot is basically a file, but can only be used for one-way communication.

Answer (score 1):

mailslots can be used if you're communication is one-way and your messages are small.  Otherwise I'd recommend using named pipes (as others have recommended).

here's something on [mailslots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576(VS.85).aspx)

[All IPC mechanisms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's helpful, if it's not critical that this be interprocess communication (if the functionality you require out of one can be shaped into a DLL which both use or similar) you can use the Common Language Runtime for interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be Sockets or RPC. I'm not familiar with pipes, but it seems to be a popular option too.